# Save and restore slider state

Tags: c#, slider, windows-8, microsoft-metro, state

How do I save and restore the state of a slider in a C# metro style app?
In a metro style app a slider needs to have its state saved when the app goes dormant.
What is the C# code to save the state of a slider?
What is the C# code to restore the state of a slider?

Comment: This should help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx. You need to handle the event when the applications goes in a suspended state, and when it resumes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the [Suspending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.application.suspending.aspx) and [Resuming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.application.resuming.aspx) events. Save your data when your application is going in suspended state, and set it when the resuming event is fired.